# Android Deskclock Alarm Toggling

Tags: android, android-intent, clock

Is there any way to toggle an alarm on/off in the stock Deskclock app programatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, sorry. On newer versions of Android, there is a documented `Intent` to allow the user to add an alarm, but that's it.

Comment: Yea, I've tried that. Cannot seem to get it to work. I would think it odd if it didn't work with Google's own deskclock. Thanks anyway!